# What hardware improvements should we make to speed up our build machine?

Tags: performance, msbuild, build-process, continuous-integration, hardware

We have a build machine running in our development department, which we've set up to build continuously throughout the working day.
What this does is:

- Deletes the source code previously checked out (5 minutes)
- Does a clean checkout from subversion (15 minutes)
- Builds a whole bunch of C++ and .NET code (35 minutes)
- Builds installers and run unit tests (5 minutes)

Given the above, what sort of impact would adding different hardware have on improving the time it takes to do the above?

For example - I was thinking about using an SSD for the harddisk as compiling involves a lot of random disk access.

The subversion server is currently a virtual machine - would switching it to be a physical machine help the slow checkout?

What impact would upgrading from a Core 2 Duo processor to an i7 make?

Any other suggestions on speeding up the above?

Comment: How much of this is already done in parallel ? e.g. are you checking out different projects in parallel, and are you doing a parallel build ? (I find it odd wiping out a previous checkout is taking 5 minutes though..)

Comment: None of it is really being done in parallel. The delete takes a long time because there is a lot of code, and the C++ projects generate a large intermediate files. The end result is that we have to delete more than 5GB of data spread across a very large number of files. What I might try is moving the old source code rather than deleting it, as this is pretty much instantaneous.

Comment: You specifically ask for hardware solutions, but I see a software optimization: your svn checkout. Rather than deleting and doing a fresh checkout, we wrote a script that does an svn status, parses its output, and uses it to delete all the unversioned files and revert all the versioned files, and then just do an svn update. Shaves a *lot* of time off each build. The only downside is that if we stop a build while it's in the middle of an svn operation, it locks the working copy and we have to manually unlock before builds will pass again. We figure it's worth that inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick that might speed up the SVN checkout process could be to have a working copy on the build machine, update the working copy and do a [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) from the working copy to the build directory. This should reduce the load on the SVN server and reduce network traffic.

Another trick to reduce the first 5 minutes of cleaning could be to move the old build dir to a temp folder on the same disk and then use another background task to delete the old build dir when the main build completes (could be a nightly cleanup task).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've modified the build to move rather than delete, which is almost instantaneous. A scheduled task now runs in the early morning to delete all the old builds from the previous day. Tried doing this is a separate thread during the build process but it got a bit messy :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you've made good suggestions yourself. Definitely add a faster hard-drive (SSD or otherwise) and upgrade the CPU as well. I think your code repository (Subversion) should definitely be on a physical machine, ideally separate from your build machine. I think you'll notice a big difference after upgrading the hardware. Also, make sure the machine doesn't have any other large tasks running at the same time as the build tasks (e.g. virus scanning) so that the build tasks aren't slowed down.

How is your build machine setup to execute its tasks? Are you using continuous integration software? Is the machine itself a server or just a regular desktop machine?

Comment: It's just a regular desktop machine. It's running MSBuild and executing a lot of custom build tasks in addition to building the solutions.

Comment: You definitely need to beef up that desktop machine. I would also suggest using a continuous integration server such as Hudson to automate these tasks. I have found it to be very useful.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the virus scanners. On one occasion our build time dropped from 50 minutes to 2 minutes when virus scanner was disabled.

Comment: We've found that msbuild builds are *slower* with an SSD. We assume it's because of all the random writes the compiler makes to obj directories and such. You might want to consider a fast hard drive with a big on-disk cache, maybe even RAID.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to speed up SVN is to use binary protocol instead of HTTP.

It looks like the build time is the most time consuming part - that's the best candidate for optimization. What about parallel build spread over other machines in the office - products like [Incredibuild](http://www.xoreax.com/) might significantly improve compilation time.